# JSON array in array from SQL database using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I have the following code:

```
$retarray = array();
  $hoursarray = array();
  $res = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, groupby FROM scheduler_activity WHERE gewerbe = '$this->gewerbe'");
  while($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $foo = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT dow, start, end FROM scheduler_businesshours WHERE activity = '$row->id'");
    while($hours = $foo->fetch_object()){
      $hoursarray[] = $hours;
    }
    $retarray[] = $row;
    $retarray["businessHours"] = $hoursarray;
  }
  return $retarray;
```

And the following JSON output:

```
{
"0": {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Spinning",
    "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
},
"businessHours": [{
    "dow": "[1,2,3]",
    "start": "17:00:00",
    "end": "18:00:00"
}, {
    "dow": "[4,5]",
    "start": "17:30:00",
    "end": "18:30:00"
}],
"1": {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Massage",
    "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
},
"2": {
    "id": "3",
    "title": "Yoga",
    "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
},
"3": {
    "id": "4",
    "title": "Dance Academy",
    "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
}
```

}

So far it looks correct but I need to get rid of the leading numbers like 0, 1, 2, 3

That it will look like this plus the businessHours:

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "Spinning",
  "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "title": "Massage",
  "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
}, {
  "id": "3",
  "title": "Yoga",
  "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
}, {
  "id": "4",
  "title": "Dance Academy",
  "groupby": "Trainingsgruppe"
}]
```

What did I do wrong there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understood about your code, we get business hour for each activity, so it's just a small change at line 10:

```
$retarray = array();
$hoursarray = array();
$res = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, groupby FROM scheduler_activity WHERE gewerbe = '$this->gewerbe'");
while($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $foo = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT dow, start, end FROM scheduler_businesshours WHERE activity = '$row->id'");
    while($hours = $foo->fetch_object()){
        $hoursarray[] = $hours;
    }
    $row["businessHours"] = $hoursarray; // Change to this, swap line 10 & 11
    $retarray[] = $row;

}
return $retarray;
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, when I do this i get the following error: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Nevermind I got it. I had to use $row->businessHours and not $row['businessHours] or i have to change it to fetch_assoc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You add two keys. One key is numeric the second is `businessHours`.

```
$retarray[] = $row;
$retarray["businessHours"] = $hoursarray;
```

For instance you can add it `businessHours` to `$row`

```
$row["businessHours"] = $hoursarray;
$retarray[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try array_values($array)?

```
$retarray = array();
  $hoursarray = array();
  $res = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT id, title, groupby FROM scheduler_activity WHERE gewerbe = '$this->gewerbe'");
  while($row = $res->fetch_object()) {
    $foo = $this->mysqli->query("SELECT dow, start, end FROM scheduler_businesshours WHERE activity = '$row->id'");
    while($hours = $foo->fetch_object()){
      $hoursarray[] = $hours;
    }
    $retarray[] = $row;
    $retarray["businessHours"] = $hoursarray;
  }
  return array_values($retarray);
```

Comment: This removes the numbers, but now it's missing the "businessHours" in the JSON string